# How do I get all my radio buttons answers to line up vertically with React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I have this form:

```
<Form.Group
                                as={Row}
                                name="formDemoYears"
                                controlId="formDemoYears"
                                onChange={this.props.handleChangeAsInt}
                                >
                                <Form.Label column sm={5}>
                                    1. How long have you worked for the organization?
                                    </Form.Label>
                                    <Col>
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    type="radio"
                                    label="Less than one year"
                                    value="Less than one year"
                                    name="formDemoYears"
                                    id="formDemoYears-1"
                                    defaultChecked={this.props.formDemoYears === "Less than one year"}
                                />
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    type="radio"
                                    label="One year to less than two years"
                                    value="One year to less than two years"
                                    name="formDemoYears"
                                    id="formDemoYears-2"
                                    defaultChecked={this.props.formDemoYears === "One year to less than two years"}
                                />
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    type="radio"
                                    label="Two years to less than five years"
                                    value="Two years to less than five years"
                                    name="formDemoYears"
                                    id="formDemoYears-3"
                                    defaultChecked={this.props.formDemoYears === "Two years to less than five years"}
                                />
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    type="radio"
                                    label="Five years to less than ten years"
                                    value="Five years to less than ten years"
                                    name="formDemoYears"
                                    id="formDemoYears-4"
                                    defaultChecked={this.props.formDemoYears === "Five years to less than ten years"}
                                />
                                <Form.Check
                                    inline
                                    type="radio"
                                    label="Ten years or more"
                                    value="Ten years or more"
                                    name="formDemoYears"
                                    id="formDemoYears-5"
                                    defaultChecked={this.props.formDemoYears === "Ten years or more"}
                                />
                                </Col>
                                </Form.Group>
```

I want all the answers to line up vertically on the right side, so it's each to see how many options you have to choose from.  However, they keep lining up like in the image below. How do I fix that? Am I missing an option?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This layout seems to be fine, only the problem with the <form.check element since these elements are inline elements, all are fields are appearing one after another

you can achieve expected layout by just wrapping <Form.check field with Row like below

```
  <Row>
    <Form.Check
      inline
      type="radio"
      label="One year to less than two years"
      value="One year to less than two years"
      name="formDemoYears"
      id="formDemoYears-2"
    />
  </Row>
```

This layout change should solve your problem.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Exactly what I needed. In addition, I found to have the answers on the right of the page, I had to wrap all the checks in a <Col> as well.  Thank you!